# setting a variable for previous dice roll

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to set a variable for previous dice roll. Why doesn't this simple line of code work? It never generates that they are the same when sometimes the random number will be the same 2 times in a row. Appreciate the help in trying to understand this.

```js
var previousDice;

function diceRoll() {
    dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1;
    console.log(dice)
    if (dice === previousDice){
        console.log(dice);
        console.log(previousDice);
        console.log('They are the same');
    }
   previousDice = dice 
}

diceRoll();
```

Comment: try returning the value into previousDice//// like so

Comment: it did for me, have you tried calling the diceRoll() multiple times after defining the function. if you have it just once and keep refreshing the page previousDice is always going to be undefined and not equal with dice which is a number.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine - what am I not understanding?
To avoid confusion, only log that they are the same in the if block.

Comment: When you repeatedly run your code the value of your variables are lost after the run.  Either create a loop or investigate saving your value to a file or local storage.

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu is correct - do a loop, say: `for(var i=0;i<20;i++) diceRoll();`.

Answer (score 1):

couple things. storing data in the global is meh. storing in an object on the global = easier. storing related functionality on that object is how we get object oriented programming.
this below is a working example.

```
const dice = {
    value:0, 
    roll: function(){
        let r= Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1;
        console.log(r, "is roll", dice.value, "is last");
        if (r=== dice.value){
            console.log(r,dice.value,'they are the same');
        }
        dice.value = r;
    }
}

dice.roll();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can have `diceRoll` as a recursive function which calls itself
> until the random value is not the previous value

```
let previousDice;

function diceRoll(previousDice) {
    const dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (dice === previousDice) {
        console.log({ dice, previousDice });
        console.log('They are the same');
        return diceRoll(previousDice);
    }

    return dice;
}

const newDice = diceRoll(previousDice);
previousDice = newDice;
```